# Unable to test pgr_dijkstra algorithm in pgRouting 2.1.0

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am using PostgeSQL 9.5 and pgRouting 2.1.0. I am trying to test pgRouting tool in my postgres DB by following this tutorial [pgRouting 2.0 for Quick Windows Guide](https://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/). Although the tutorial assumes road transport network data of Vienna in GEOJSON format but due to unavailability of data at mentioned link, I used my own data and converted the ESRI shapefile (16,060 rows) to GEOJSON using QGIS. Then, I used QGIS DB Manager to import street.geojson file to my postgres "routing" DB. As per tutorial, I used following commands to add "source" and "target" columns as well as to create topology.

```
alter table public.street add column source integer;
alter table public.street add column target integer;
select pgr_createTopology('public.street', 0.0001, 'geom', 'id');
```

However, when I used following set of commands to test pgr_dijkstra algorithm:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, geom
FROM pgr_dijkstra(
  'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(geom) as cost FROM public.street',
  1, 3000, false, false
  ) as di
JOIN public.street pt
ON di.id2 = pt.id;
```

the query runs successfully but I am not getting any output.

[image: Output Screenshot]

Can anyone help me to understand what's wrong with my processing?

EDIT:

After running the query to identify the records, the results are as under:

[image: Query Results]

Comment: Do those nodes exist (1 and 3000) in your street table?

Comment: @LR1234567: I used pgr_createTopology() function and it processed all 16,000+ edges. I hope your query is related to this. I can see source and target column values for all 16,060 rows when I view the data in street table in postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass in the ID of the src and dest records.

Run this statement to help you identify the records you are looking for:

```
SELECT id, source, target
FROM public.street
WHERE (id = 1 or id = 3000)
    or (src = 1 or src = 3000)
    or (dest = 1 or dest = 3000);
```

You passed id=1 for src and id=3000 for dest into pgr_Dijkstra. The records it is using are row 2 for src (with a source=31) and row 4 as dest (with a target=5460).

If you are wanting row 1 and row 7 then you need to pass id=1386 as src (with source=1) and id=10392 as dest (with target=3000).

Comment: Okay, after running this query I am able to see three columns of ids source and targets. Can you please be specific how does it help to resolve the above problem? Since I used my own data, this could be a problem but above code worked already on the page I mentioned.

Comment: @JibranKhan can you display the results please?  Edit your question and add the screenshot.

Comment: I have edited the question and results have been added as a screen shot! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JibranKhan You passed 1 for src and 3000 for dest into pgr_Dijkstra.  The records it is using are row 2 for src and row 4 as dest.  If you are wanting row 1 and row 7 then you need to pass 1386 as src and 10392 as dest.

Comment: You are right. I passed wrong records for source and target. I am getting output at least after passing correct values. But, I am not getting cost and other values for all rows like the one shown at tutorial link. The problem looks like my data is not noded!